# Почему python пропускает строки в csv файлах?

Tags: python, excel, csv

Я пытаюсь записать в excel таблицу данные, но python записавыет данные через строку, а не в каждую строку.

```py
with open("all_categories_dict.json",encoding='utf-8') as file:
    all_categories = json.load(file)
    
    iteration_count = int(len(all_categories)) - 1
    count = 0
    print(f"всего итераций: {iteration_count}")
    for category_name, category_href in all_categories.items():
    
        rep = [",", " ", "-", "'"]
        for item in rep:
            if item in category_name:
                category_name = category_name.replace(item, "_")
        req = requests.get(url=category_href, headers=headers)
        src = req.text
    
        with open(f"data/{count}_{category_name}.html", "w", encoding='utf-8') as file:
            file.write(src)
    
        with open(f"data/{count}_{category_name}.html", encoding='utf-8') as file:
            src = file.read()
    
        soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")
    
        # поверка страницы на наличие таблицы с продуктами
        alert_block = soup.find(class_='uk-alert-danger')
        if alert_block is not None:
            continue
    
        # собираем заголовки таблицы
        table_head = soup.find(class_="mzr-tc-group-table").find("tr").find_all("th")
        product = table_head[0].text
        calories = table_head[1].text
        proteins = table_head[2].text
        fats = table_head[3].text
        carbohydrates = table_head[4].text
    
        with open(f"data/{count}_{category_name}.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8-sig") as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
            writer.writerow(
                (
                    product,
                    calories,
                    proteins,
                    fats,
                    carbohydrates
                )
            )
        
        # собираем данные продуктов
        products_data = soup.find(class_="mzr-tc-group-table").find("tbody").find_all("tr")
    
        product_info = []
        for item in products_data:
            product_tds = item.find_all("td")
    
            title = product_tds[0].find("a").text
            calories = product_tds[1].text
            proteins = product_tds[2].text
            fats = product_tds[3].text
            carbohydrates = product_tds[4].text
    
            product_info.append(
                {
                    "Title": title,
                    "Calories": calories,
                    "Proteins": proteins,
                    "Fats": fats,
                    "Carbohydrates": carbohydrates
                }
            )
    
            with open(f"data/{count}_{category_name}.csv", "a", encoding="utf-8-sig") as file:
                _writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
                _writer.writerow(
                    (
                        title,
                        calories,
                        proteins,
                        fats,
                        carbohydrates
                    )
                )
            
        with open(f"data/{count}_{category_name}.json", "a", encoding="utf-8") as file:
            json.dump(product_info, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Результат выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Ссылка на саму таблицу](https://1drv.ms/x/s!ApuTtOc86djvg-xpOSPBb5e1ewaYKQ?e=TfEOG2)

Comment: А вы уверены, что у вас, например, в строке `carbohydrates` нет в конце перевода строки либо наоборот в начале переменной `title`? Добавьте к вопросу пример - что у вас в данных, как выглядит получающийся файл. Ну и это ведь не весь код, может вы ещё где-то в этот же файл пишете? Может вы туда пустой набор данных пишете, например? Нужно больше информации.

Comment: Я добавил почти весь код, и на скриншоте результат. Добавление данных проиходить путем парсинга с сайта. Пропуски появляются только при записи в csv файл, если просто печатать данные в терминал пропусков нет.

Comment: Ещё бы сам `csv` файл несколько строк увидеть. Если, конечно, хотите докопаться до сути, а не обойтись костылями.

Comment: @CrazyElf Я добавил ссылку на таблицу. Хоть решение ниже и работает, я действительно хочу разобраться.

Comment: Ладно, что-то мне некогда разбираться и пишут вот, что это нормальный способ - просто убрать перевод строки в конце. Если только вы сами разберётесь потом как-нибудь )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```py
with open(f"data/{count}_{category_name}.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8-sig",  newline='') as file:
```

согласен с комментарием, исправил согласно @insolor

Comment: Помогло, спасибо!

Comment: @lian.lun пользуйтесь на здоровье, сейчас документацию добавлю в ответ

Comment: Выглядит как костыль, прячущий за собой реальную проблему

Comment: @andreymal что built-in мне предлагает, то и пользую. Входных данных все равно нет, а гадать - не благодарное дело

Comment: Я добавил ссылку на таблицу, был бы рад разобраться.

Comment: @andreymal, в доках по модулю csv примеры именно с таким способом открытия файла даются: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer

Comment: @Dmitry лучше на строке где идет открытие csv файла показывать, для json этот параметр не нужен.

Comment: @insolor вот хороший ответ должен был бы содержать цитату из документации (впрочем, даже сама документация описывает это так, что всё равно похоже на костыль, ну да ладно)